# Jetpack Compose, how to test UI node which is displayed after loading API call?

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose

In my applcation I'm showing a LazyColumn which consists of itinerary list. The itineraries come retrofit api call and it takes a few seconds to load. When they're loading, the CircularProgressIndicator is being displayed. I want to test that when I click on LazyColumn item, it navigates to another screen. The issue is that I retrieve the data from the network. How can I test the click funcionality in this case?

It looks like this, but when I launch the app the itineraries are loaded with entry data.

[image: ezgif com-video-to-gif (2)]

**My test (doesn't work)**

```
Test
    fun navigation_navigateToInfoScreen() {

        composeTestRule
            .waitUntil(
                timeoutMillis = 5000
            ) {
                composeTestRule
                    .onAllNodesWithTag(Constants.TEST_TAG_FLIGHT_LAZY_COLUMN)
                    .fetchSemanticsNodes().size == 1
            }

        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(Constants.TEST_TAG_FLIGHT_LAZY_COLUMN)
            .onChildren()
            .onFirst()
            .performClick()
        val route = navController.currentDestination?.route
        assertThat(route).isEqualTo(Screen.Info.route)
    }

}
```